# Does the concept of ibur exist today?

Tags: soul, modern-times, reincarnation

The shaar hagilgulim frequently addresses the concept of iburim, that souls from passed on people may enter new bodies.

For source, see for example shaar hagilgulim 1.8:
"According to this, you can also understand another well known concept of our rabbis: ruchot or neshamot of the righteous are infused into a person, in accord with the esoteric principle called “ibur,” to assist a person in his service of G‑d."

Does this concept exist also today? I mean, can you experience an ibur of a tzaddik in your lifetime?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think anything metaphysical has changed since that work was composed?

Comment: DoubleAA: My reason for thinking this is from a statement in shaarhagilgulim where the author points out that a smaller portion of people in later times will be able to merit their nefesh: "Having said this, we can answer an important question. The majority of people only merit their Nefesh. And only a small amount in these later generations ever merit to their Ruach and Neshama. Yet, we know that the son of David will not come until all the Ruchot and Neshamot are rectified (Talmud Yebamot 62a)." Source: Shaarhagilgulim 4.5

Comment: @Levi Don't you think it would be helpful to anyone reading this question if you have included that in your post along with any other information/motivation/expectations you may have? Please [edit] to improve your post.

Comment: There is a statement in the Zohar that says moshe rabbeinu who was the first redeemer will be the last redeemer. On the other hand moshiach needs to be from David hamelech. This is explained by commentaries as being possible as a result of gilgul and ibur

Comment: What exactly is the difference between ibur and gilgul?

Comment: @DonielF Gilgul is when a soul reincarnates into a new person. Ibur is when a soul transmigrates into a person that's already alive.

Comment: @ikay Olay. That's a little creepy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rav Moshe David Wali](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99) (18th century) writes in the ספר הליקוטים page 26 (חלק א'‏):

> ועוד לו המשכה פרטית מן הפרטית בין בתלמוד בין במעשה שבא לו סיוע מנשמותיהן של צדיקים ושל חכמים, ואם הוא מעיין בספר פלוני יבוא לו סיוע להבין ולהשכיל מנשמתו של פלוני שחיבר אותו. וכל שכן אם הוא יכוין בכך בעת לימודו, ואפילו במאמר אחד בלבד יבוא לו סיוע להבינו מבעל המאמר עצמו, [ע"י] עיבור הנשמות, שהוא דבר גדול שנעשה תמיד בכל רגע אם טוב ואם רע כפי מעשיו של אדם, שמתעברים בו נשמותיהם של צדיקים אם יבוא לעשות טוב, וז"ס: שמסייען אותו למי שבא ליטהר, ומתעברים בו נשמותיהם של רשעים כשבא לעשות רע, כי מצא מין את מינו וניעור, וימצא מנוח בדומה לו. והעיבור נעשה בין בנשמה על ידי המחשבה, בין ברוח על ידי הדיבור, בין בנפש על ידי המעשה, ולכן המשכיל יזהר מאד בג' אלו, לשמור אותם מתוקנים כראוי כדי שיזכה לעיבורם מצד הטוב, כי פואל אדם ישלם לו וכארח איש ימציאנו.‏

So it looks like the answer is "yes" and "constantly".